# sitecore: broken loginpage. page simply refreshes and doens't redirect

Tags: authentication, sitecore

I'm creating a sitecore website. At some point i  noticed that the sitecore loginpage isn't working properly anymore. It still responds to correct/incorrect credentials but the page doens't change.
It seems af if the loginpage simply refreshes.

( I noticed this issue after i changed the authentication to windows AD authentication. Not sure if this is the culprit. I didn't use the loginpage for some time.)

Does anyone have a idea as to what might cause this ?

Comment: Have you checked the logs?

Comment: What is the <authentication> node mode value ?

Comment: @AhmedOkour Logs don't say much. Simply says " INFO  AUDIT (sitecore\admin): Login ". Nothing else

Comment: @nsgocev  <authentication mode="Windows">

Comment: @Timon - I guess you are using the Active Directory Module. Have you executed the steps listed here on page 25: http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/modules/ad/12/sitecore_active_directory_module_guide_sc72-80-a4.pdf. I have had this error when I messed up the authentication modes. In the web.config. The generic sitecore login page is using forms authentication and it is normal for it not to respond when you are forcing windows authentication.

Comment: @nsgocev I changed it back to <authentication mode="Forms"> but no change.

Comment: @Timon, are you attempting to login as an AD user or a Sitecore user? If it's the later, are you prefixing the username with `sitecore\\`.

Comment: @DerekHunziker Makes no difference. with or without prefix the page simply does nothing ( Except for refreshing the Browser Notes section on the bottom right ). If I enter wrong credentials the page tells me this.